# How can I figure out if the first character of an argument is \?

Tags: macros, characters, arguments

I have defined a new command that displays a box around whatever I want inside, and want it to act differently depending on whether its argument is just plain text or another command (e.g. `\includegraphics`).

To do so, I reckon it would be simple to check if the first character of the argument is `\`. I've tried with `\StrChar` from the `xstring` package, but it doesn't seem to be happy about it.

```
\newcommand{\extractFirst}[1]{
   \StrChar{#1}{1}[\FirstChar]
   The first character is: '\FirstChar'\par
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: I think a bit more context is needed here: will the argument be either text or a single control sequence? You might give a look at [What is the best way to check if an argument of a control sequence is a control sequence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307347/82917).

Comment: your macro does not get the sequence of characters starting with `\ ` it gets a single token which prints as a `\abc` command name but is internally a single entry in the table of defined commands .

Answer (score 2):

Here, I make use of an internal macro from the `tokcycle` package.

The `\count@stringtoks` macro is used to count the tokens that make up the `\string` of the argument.  We rely on the fact that the `\string` of a character token will be a single byte in length, whereas the `\string` of any macro token will be at least two bytes in length.  Using this criterion, we can differentiate a macro from a character.

Best of all, `\count@stringtoks` is fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\extractFirst[1]{\testfirst#1\relax\relax}
\def\testfirst#1#2\relax{\tctestifnum{\count@stringtoks{#1}>1}{Macro}{Character}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\extractFirst{abc}

\extractFirst{a}

\extractFirst{\abc ab\c}

\extractFirst{\a ab\c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted to avoid loading the package, the extracted code necessary to recreate the `\count@stringtoks` macro is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\extractFirst[1]{\testfirst#1\relax\relax}
\def\testfirst#1#2\relax{\tctestifnum{\count@stringtoks{#1}>1}{Macro}{Character}}
% FROM TOKCYCLE:
\long\def\count@stringtoks#1{\tc@earg\count@toks{\string#1}}
\long\def\count@toks#1{\the\numexpr-1\count@@toks#1.\tc@endcnt}
\long\def\count@@toks#1#2\tc@endcnt{+1\tc@ifempty{#2}{\relax}{\count@@toks#2\tc@endcnt}}
\def\tc@ifempty#1{\tc@testxifx{\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax}}
\long\def\tc@earg#1#2{\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}
\long\def\tctestifnum#1{\tctestifcon{\ifnum#1\relax}}
\long\def\tctestifcon#1{#1\expandafter\tc@exfirst\else\expandafter\tc@exsecond\fi}
\long\def\tc@testxifx{\tc@earg\tctestifx}
\long\def\tctestifx#1{\tctestifcon{\ifx#1}}
\long\def\tc@exfirst#1#2{#1}
\long\def\tc@exsecond#1#2{#2}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\extractFirst{abc}

\extractFirst{a}

\extractFirst{\abc ab\c}

\extractFirst{\a ab\c}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the input with `expl3` functions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommandmacro}{m}{%
  \fcolorbox{red}{white}{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommandnomacro}{m}{%
  \fcolorbox{blue}{black!10}{#1}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
   {
    \peek_catcode:NTF \c_group_begin_token
     {% argument starts with brace
      \ballu_mycommand_nomacro:w
     }
     {
      \ballu_mycommand_test:Nw
     }
    #1 \q_stop
   }
 }


\cs_new:Npn \ballu_mycommand_nomacro:w #1 \q_stop
 {
  \mycommandnomacro{#1}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \ballu_mycommand_test:Nw #1 #2 \q_stop
 {
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1
   {
    \mycommandmacro{#1#2}
   }
   {
    \mycommandnomacro{#1#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycommand{abc}

\mycommand{{ab}c}

\mycommand{\mbox{abc}}

\mycommand{{\mbox{abc}}def}

X\mycommand{}X

X\mycommand{ }X

\end{document}
```

Blank (empty or just spaces) arguments do nothing at all; this might be changed, here it is used for defensive programming.

An initial brace triggers the “nomacro” variant.

[image]