# Allow spaces between arguments in a macro definition

Tags: tex-core, expl3

I don't know if it's right to allow this kind of practice, but I've been asked many times. How do you allow spaces between square brackets and parentheses in the code below?
I try to use `\@ifnextchar` unsuccessfully, perhaps it's easier with `expl3`

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\DrawPolygon{\@ifnextchar[{\@DrawPolygon}{\@DrawPolygon[]}}
\def\@DrawPolygon[#1](#2,#3)#4{%
 \begingroup
 \draw[#1] (#2)
     \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 \endgroup
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (B) at (2,0); 
\coordinate (C) at (2,2); 
\coordinate (D) at (0,3);

\DrawPolygon  [red](A,...,D)  {mypolygon} %ok
% problem with \DrawPolygon  [red] (A,...,D)  {mypolygon}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to xparse, a simple adjustment to your existing definition would be to change

```
\def\@DrawPolygon[#1](#2,#3)#4{%
 \begingroup
 \draw[#1] (#2)
     \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 \endgroup
}
```

to

```
\def\@DrawPolygon[#1]#2(#3,#4)#5{%
 \begingroup
 \draw[#1] (#3)
     \foreach \pt in {#3,#4}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 \endgroup
}
```

which would allow spaces (or anything) between `]` and `(`.

You could of course check that #2 at most contains spaces if you wanted to check for that, but the macro is already silently discarding `#4` (now `#5`) so doing the same for the new `#2` doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: Interesting! We're often surprised with the programming of TeX

Comment: I was beginning to read more seriously some documents on L3 ...

Comment: @AlainMatthes that is a good thing to do, but...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xparse`. The first argument is optional with default value empty; the second argument is anything from `(` to a comma, the third argument anything up to `)`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawPolygon}{O{}r(,u)m}{%
  \draw[#1] (#2) \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,2); \coordinate (D) at (0,3);

\DrawPolygon  [red](A,...,D)  {mypolygon}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0); \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,2); \coordinate (D) at (0,3);

\DrawPolygon  [red] (A,...,D)  {mypolygon}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It would be probably better to avoid `u` argument type, but for this application it seems adequate.

[image]

A code that avoids `u`:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawPolygon}{O{}r()m}
 {
  \am_drawpolygon:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \am_drawpolygon:nnn
 {
  \draw[#1](\clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 }) \foreach \pt in {#2}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: thanks ! so far I've only seen a few examples with ‘xparse' but I haven't studied it yet. Why it's better to avoid `u`? Do  you have a solution without `xparse`?

Comment: After reading the doc quickly my only problem is `r(,u)` , more specifically `,u`

Comment: @AlainMatthes I added the definition without `u` argument. The original reads: first argument is optional with default value empty: `O{}`; second argument is anything between `(` and `,`: `r(,)`; third argument is anything up to `)`: `u)`

Comment: I need time to understand (to learn) the code without `u` . About the presence of `,u` in the first solution, I suppose that it has something to do with `#2,#3`

Comment: @AlainMatthes There is ***no*** `,u`. It is `O{} r(, u) m`. The argument type `r` has to be followed by two tokens.

Comment: ok now I found ; Backwards Compatibility and I understand ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \alain_draw_poly:nw #1#2,#3\q_stop
  {
    \group_begin:
    \draw[#1] (#2)
       \foreach \pt in {#2,#3} {--(\pt)} -- cycle;
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \DrawPolygon { O{} R(){} }
  {
    \alain_draw_poly:nw {#1} #2 \q_stop
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,2);
\coordinate (D) at (0,3);

\DrawPolygon  [red] (A,...,D)  {mypolygon}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `\@DrawPolygon` in the MWE doesn't use its `#4`. Here is an enhanced version of the code that creates a node at the centroid of the polygon, with `#4` as the node contents:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g__alain_pts_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \alain_draw_poly:nwn #1#2,#3\q_stop #4
  {
    \group_begin:
    \draw[#1] (#2)
      \foreach \pt in {#2,#3} {--(\pt)} -- cycle;

    \seq_gclear:N \g__alain_pts_seq
    \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}
      { \seq_gput_right:Nx \g__alain_pts_seq { \exp_not:V \pt =1 } }

    \node at (barycentric~cs \c_colon_str \seq_use:Nn \g__alain_pts_seq { , })
      {#4};
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \DrawPolygon { O{} R(){} m }
  {
    \alain_draw_poly:nwn {#1} #2 \q_stop {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,2);
\coordinate (D) at (0,3);

\DrawPolygon  [red] (A,...,D)  {My polygon}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: About `#4` yes in my example but it's possible in other cases. I want to learn ...

Comment: Right, at first I wanted to use it, but since there is no `\node` command here, there was no obvious place. I imagine you would like to compute an average coordinate to place a node?

Comment: Often the macros I use are of this form.  Why `\q_stop` that egreg doesn't use?

Comment: `\cs_new_protected:Npn \alain_draw_poly:nw #1#2,#3\q_stop` is like a `\protected\long\def`. Here, `#3` is a *delimited argument* for TeX, `\q_stop` is the standard delimiter used in such situations in `expl3` AFAIK, like `\@nil` in LaTeX2e. egreg used it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527279/73317) for instance. :-) (`#2` is also a delimited argument here, the delimiter being a comma of catcode 12). So, the `\cs_new_protected:Npn ...` is akin to `\protected\long\def\yourmacro #1#2,#3\@nil`, if you understand this better.

Comment: I added an enhanced version of the code that creates a node at the centroid of the polygon, with `#4` as the node contents.